# Test if piped program is waiting for input

Tags: python, pipe

When I want to write a program that shows console in- and output of another program in a gui, I need to know if the program is waiting for input, to update the input window and enable the input-textbox. I call the other program with `subprocess.Popen`. How do you test that? (The other program does `time.sleep(n)` and long time calculations, so I can't test if the output doesn't change after some time as testing for waiting.)

Comment: Does the subprocess provide any prompts? For example it prints `password:` then waits for a password.

Comment: While the program can output any text, I do not want to risk, if the output prints such strings for example as a listing of a file.

Comment: You should accept input and  write to `stdin`. Once the process is done with its heavy computation, it should be able to read from `stdin`. Instead of disabling the text box, add a progress bar to show input processing progress.